# Changing the format of date after picking from datepicker after SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, sapui5, date-formatting

I have a datepicker from which I want to extract the date and display in a label. Currently the date is getting displayed in the format MM/DD/YYYY but I want it in the format MMM dd, yyyy (Nov 17, 2017). Below is the code :

```
screenDate=view.byId("screeningDate").getValue();
var date = view.byId("__date");
date.setText(screenDate);
```

XML :

```
    <HBox alignItems="Center" renderType="Bare">
                    <Label text="Date of Screening" width="50%"/>
                    <DatePicker class="sapUiLargeMarginBegin" width="50%" id="screeningDate"/>
                </HBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Naveen's answer here's the solution with your existing code:

```
screenDate=view.byId("screeningDate").getValue();
var date = view.byId("__date");
// Make date object out of screenDate
var dateObject = new Date(screenDate);
// SAPUI5 date formatter
var dateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({pattern : "MMM dd,YYYY" }); 
// Format the date
var dateFormatted = dateFormat.format(dateObject);
date.setText(dateFormatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, By getting view controls and updating the property in it is not good. It will be good if you have a model.

Solution for your problem is below,

```
<Label text="{
            path: '/date',
            type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
            formatOptions: {
                style: 'medium',
                pattern: 'MMM dd, yyyy'
            }}"/>
<DatePicker dateValue="{/date}"/>
```

And in the controller I have a JSONModel as below,

```
onInit : function() {
    this.model = new JSONModel({
        date : new Date(0)
    });
    this.getView().setModel(this.model);
}
```